# Question from number theory related to GCD

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $a,b,c$ be integers such that $(a,b) = 1$, $c>0$. Prove that there is an integer $x$ such that $(a+bx,c) = 1$.

Comment: Have you seen [Bezout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)?

Answer (score 1):

Let $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ be the prime factors of $c$. Take $x$ such that $$x\equiv\begin{cases} -\frac{a}{b} & p_i\nmid b \\ 0 & p_i\mid b\end{cases}\pmod{p_i}.$$ This is possible by the Chinese Remainder Theorem. It’s easy to see that this $x$ will satisfy the required condition.

Alternatively, take $x$ such that $a+bx$ is prime: this is possible by Dirichlet’s Theorem.

Comment: It can be proved much more simply - see the linked dupe.

Comment: @BillDubuque I mean, our arguments are pretty similar. The $x$ I’m constructing and the $z$ you constructed satisfy the same essential property.

Comment: But there is not use of CRT there (and I show how it follows from a very simple idea)